# Why am I getting IndexError: list index out of range in this code?

Tags: python, sorting, indexing, double, direction

Im trying to make a two way bubble sort.  on odd iterations, it bubbles and sorts to the right, on even iterations, it bubbles and sorts to the left.

```
def main():

    myList = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
    lengthOfList = len(myList)
    firstThresh = 0
    lastThresh = lengthOfList
    oddPass = True
    while firstThresh <= lastThresh:
        if oddPass == True:
            for index in myList[firstThresh:lastThresh]:                
                if myList[index] > myList[index+1]:      <==================
                    temp = myList[index]
                    myList[index] = myList[index+1]
                    myList[index+1] = temp
                    print(myList)
                    oddPass = False
            lastThresh -= 1
        else:
            for index in reversed(myList[firstThresh:lastThresh]):
                if myList[index] < myList[index-1]:
                    temp = myList[index]
                    myList[index] = myList[index-1]
                    myList[index+1] = temp
                    print(myList)
                   oddPass = False
            firstThresh += 1
main()
```

The error:
line 22, in bubbleSort2Way
    if myList[index] > myList[index+1]:
IndexError: list index out of range

I put the arrow where the problem is.
I am a beginner at programming so if its obvious im sorry!
Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
for index in myList[firstThresh:lastThresh]:
```

is using the values from `myList`, not the index. So the code is trying to access the 11th element (index "10") on a list with only 10 elements and getting an out of range error.

To use the index in your loop, change this line to

```
for index, value in enumerate(myList[firstThresh:lastThresh]):
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  It worked, however, once the 10 gets sorted to the right it gives the same error at the same spot.  Do you know why that is? Visualized :                                                                                            [9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[9, 8, 10, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[9, 8, 7, 10, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 10, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 10, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 10, 3, 2, 1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 10, 2, 1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 10, 1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10]

Comment: Did you also change this line `for index in reversed(myList[firstThresh:lastThresh]):` to use the enumerate function? `for index, value in enumerate(reversed(myList[firstThresh:lastThresh])):`

Comment: You are welcome! No worries..we all have bad nights. :P If this answered your question then please spread the love by accepting it as the answer.